# How to express null coalescing operator using CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, codedom, null-coalescing-operator

Let's say, I have following simplified type:

```
public class Model
{
    public decimal? Result { get; set; }
}
```

How to express null coalescing operator using CodeDOM to generate C# code, is it possible at all?
Now I'm using following workaround:

```
new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
    new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(modelArgument, "Result"),
        "Value"))
```

Which is equal to `model.Result.Value`, but not `model.Result ?? 0M`

#### Better workaround

`CodeExpression` equalent to `model.Result.GetValueOrDefault(0M)` suitable for nullable value types

```
new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
                        new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(
                            new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(modelArgument, "Result"),
                            "GetValueOrDefault"),
                            new [] { new CodePrimitiveExpression(0m) })),
```

Comment: Just a thought, Have you tried just coding a simply POCO with a null-coalescing operator and looking at the code that's generated in IL-Dasm or reflector ?

Comment: @RussC I tried it out. The generated IL of `model.Result ?? 0M` is identical to `model.Result.HasValue ? model.Result.GetValueOrDefault() : 0M`

Comment: I thought that might be the case; the null coalesce is just a compiler trick then; that should give you a better clue on what to emit. From what I've read, instead of making a emitting a ternary operator (which seems to be disallowed) emit an If..Else block.

Comment: That's based on this link:  http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/can-ternary-conditional-expressions-represented-codedom-t3154907.html

Comment: Why don't you simply use `model.Result.GetValueOrDefault()`? Or do you also need to support other default values?

Comment: It is also possible to have `model.Result.GetValueOrDefault(10m)` where `10m` is custom default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As guys mentioned in the comment section, `??` operator is just a syntactical sugar. If you inspect `IL` code you will see condition on `HasValue` and then call to a `GetValueOrDefault` method. This method accepts a parameter, that will be returned if a Nullable object has no value, in other case it will return `Value` property.

Try to use next code, that simply call  `GetValueOrDefault` method via `CodeMethodInvokeExpression`, which is semantically equivalent to the call of null-coallesing operator. I use `4` as a default value, but in you case omiting the parameter will do the job, because you demand `0m` as a default value for a decimal.

```
new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
                        new CodeMethodReferenceExpression(
                            new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(modelArgument, "Result"),
                            "GetValueOrDefault"),
                            new [] { new CodePrimitiveExpression(0m) }));
```

Note: after inspection of `GetValueOrDefault` I found, that it uses `HasValue` property. So there is no need to call it twice (so compiler will call it twice in case of using `??` operator without optimization. In case of optimization enabled it will simply call `GetValueOrDefault`). Method contents are given below:

```
public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
{
  if (!this.HasValue)
    return defaultValue;
  else
    return this.value;
}
```